# Rails4: Restrict Controller Destroy Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I set up my current_user in the Controller so User's Cant Edit other User's Entries.

But i can get it working for the Destroy Action.

My only solution is to check if the User is the Actual Uploader and only then show him the Destroy link.

```
 <% if current_user == shop.user %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', shop, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

But isn't his a Bad Practice as someone can easily hack this ?

If someone could enlighten me on this...
Thank You :)

Comment: Does each `User` have_one `Shop` or can have_many `Shops`?

Comment: Well this is whole other issue. I tried setting it up so User's will be limited to 1 but didn't get it working. Normally the User should be having only ONE Shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. Once installed, CanCan will generate an 'Ability' file where you can define what users can or cannot do. in you case for example, you might have

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
```

Then in your views, you can do a simple check to see whether or not a user has the ability to modify that object. For instance:

```
<% if can? :destroy, shop %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', shop, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

In your controller you can authorize actions like so:

```
class ShopsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def destroy
    ....
  end
end
```

The "load_and_authorize_resource" line will automatically add authorization into each RESTful action. It would add this to your destroy action, for instance:

```
        @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
        authorize! :destroy, @shop
```

It's a super useful gem and very well documented

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Instead of passing a shop id to edit, update and destroy, you could use a singular resource(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) instead of a plural.

routes.rb:

```
resources :shops, only: :show, :index
resource :shop, only: [:new, :create, edit, :update, :destroy]
```

You will also need to change the `before_action` so it fetches the shop of the current user instead of querying by the `id` passed as parameter:

```
def set_shop
  @shop = current_user.shop
end
```

Because you are no longer fetching the shop to be destroyed/edited using an `id` provided by the web user, there is no way for him to make a custom request with a fake id.

Comment: I tried making User limited to ONE shop before, but i was hours trying and getting all error'd up. Could you Help me with that ?

Comment: You mind joining me on Chat ? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35711/controller-error-room

Answer (score 0):

You should hide it on the view, but you should also have control of it on your controller.

In your controller you must do something like a **before_action** (read about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Comment: I have already in my Controller a before_action. ->   before_action :set_shop, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy].. Could you edit your Answer with what exactly should be Changed ?